# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm moving from MySQL to MS SQL server, and trying to fetch some  data from the  table. I am connected but unsure how to fetch data with `sqlsrv`. This is how  I  made the query :

```
$sql = "SELECT ACTID, ACTTYPE, ACTDATE FROM [PROSYS].[dbo].[ACTION]";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["ACTID"]. " - Name: " . $row["ACTYPE"]. "DATE " . $row["ACDATE"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

but when execute it I have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on
> resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\connection.php on line 15

Comment: how do you connect to the db?  What is `$conn`?

Comment: Your query looks fine (NOTE though some things from MySQL to MSSQL are different syntax, so you will have to pay attention to that.  But as @WillardSolutions said, what is your connection string and are you even able to connect to the DB first?  It tells you in the error right where your error is, what is that code?

Comment: ``` $serverName = "X.X.X.X\YYYYY";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBNAME","UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"AADDADD");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

Comment: Your connection should determine the database to be used. Using three-part names will only make your code more fragile and more difficult to use in different environments.

Comment: I get hard time to just establish this connection jajaja,

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to get the result from the query,
the connection I'll take care about it later :)

```
$conn_array = array (
    "UID" => "sa",
    "PWD" => "root",
    "Database" => "nih_bw",
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect('BILAL', $conn_array);
if ($conn){
    echo "connected";
    if(($result = sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM routines")) !== false){
        while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $result )) {
              echo $obj->colName.'<br />';
        }
    }
}else{
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

i'm trying to display on a tbale now, but some Columns are done and other can't be and show this warning

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$FAMILLE
```

I use this to display

```
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $obj->ARTCODE. "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $obj->ARTDES. "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $obj->FAMILLE. "</td>";
```